# use left, mid and right functions to extract text between two characters/words?

Tags: excel, extract, formula

I have the following data in a worksheet:

```
column A
431620121601 5201585 - 0006 Fresh Turkey Gravy 500g 27 -Cartons 27 162
431619121602 5204059 - 0006 Fresh Bread Sauce 300g 52 -Palettes 52 312
```

I want to get the number of cartons or palettes from the text and put this in column B

```
Column B
    27 Cartons
    52 Palettes
```

Here's what i have tried so far:

```
=MID(A8,SEARCH(" ",A8)+12,SEARCH("-Cartons",A8)-SEARCH(" ",A8)-4)
```

but this gives me this:

```
06 Fresh Turkey Gravy 500g 27 -Cartons
```

Please can someone show me a better way of doing this?

Comment: is the hyphon "-" present in all rows?

Comment: seems like you can search for something like `"00g "` and go from there. It's not clear enough what the pattern is.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what you want but with helper columns.

[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

Col I has all possible Types listed like Cartons, Palettes etc.

Then I use these formula to get the results

To find Index of what Type is matching. this formula is to be entered as an array formula i.e. type the formula and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
B2 =SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(IF(FIND($I$2:$I$4,A2)>0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)*ROW($I$2:$I$4))
```

Get what Type is matching

```
C2 =INDEX($I$1:$I$7,B2)
```

Get the ending string

```
D2 =RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(C2,A2)+1)
```

Get the last number

```
E2 =SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D2," ",REPT(" ",50)),50)," ","")
```

replace the last number and the Type with blank and add the Type at the end

```
F2 =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,E2,""),C2,"")) & " " & C2
```

Drag all the formulas down for each row of your data. Take note of the column I.

Answer (score 0):

I know a UDF probably seems like overkill, but I am a huge fan of regular expressions, and I wish they were more mainstream within the VBA community the way they are in many other technologies.

So, with that in mind, here is a Regex solution to your problem:

```
Function UNITS(InputText As String) As String

  Dim rx As New RegExp
  Dim match As MatchCollection

  rx.Pattern = "(\d+ )-([A-Za-z]+)"

  If rx.Test(InputText) Then
    Set match = rx.Execute(InputText)
    UNITS = match(0).SubMatches(0) & match(0).SubMatches(1)
  End If

End Function
```

[image]

The best thing about the Regex is the scalability.  This can adapt in ways an inline formula would have trouble doing with irregular data.

Also, in the example above, the `rx` might be better suited as a global.

To use Regular Expressions, you will have to add a reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" to your project.

[image]